# How to send an automatic mail once file (one or multiple files) uploads into mysql database using jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I am doing project using jsp in netbeans8.2, tomcat8, java, MySQL(xampp). I have done the coding till multiple file uploads. Now I want to send email to respective user mail id, once file uploads into MySQL database. I searched but on internet but I got for only one user mail id. I need for all users who will upload one or multiple files then immediately mail notification should be sent. Is there any tutorial or suggest me any tutorial(link) that I can refer to solve my problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends which framework you are using, there are multiple ways to achieve this.

- In case you are using Spring Framework use this tutorial

  - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email
  - https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-java-mail-tutorial
- In case Plain Java

  - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email

Happy to help further as and when needed.